# DateTime.Parse throws FormatException regardless of CultureInfo

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, cultureinfo

My machine is configured with European date format: `dd/MM/yyyy`

When running any of the following lines:

```
DateTime.Parse("11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM");
DateTime.Parse("11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
DateTime.Parse("11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"));
DateTime.Parse("11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
```

I'm getting

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Why doesn't any culture info allow me to parse this date? I know in which culture the string was originally created (using `DateTime.ToString()`), but that's it, so I don't want to use `ParseExact`, unless there is some API to get the default format string per culture.

Comment: have you tried using `GetCultureInfo`?

Comment: Your second line works fine for me (while first throws exception as it should).

Comment: If you already have it as a DateTime, why are you parsing it to a string and then back to a DateTime?

Comment: @TJWolschon I have it as DateTime in another application which won't change its contract

Comment: @DanielA.White what with it? does it provide the actual format string?

Comment: And what is your original culture (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`), is it "en-US"?

Comment: @Evk, yes it is "en-US", for testing purposes, if I create the string on my machine there wouldn't be a parsing error

Comment: Then `DateTime.Parse("11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM", new CultureInfo("en-us", false));` should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work on a machine where the date pattern was left to default:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
Console.WriteLine(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
var date = DateTime.Parse("11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM", culture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

The default date pattern for en-US is "`M/d/yyyy`" and the time pattern is "`h:mm tt`".

This holds true unless you modify your system settings for the current culture, and that culture is en-US.

If you want to bypass customized settings, create a `new CultureInfo("en-US", false)`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you are configured with `dd/MM/yyyy`

thus `"11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM"` is invalid. It should be:

```
"15/11/2017 12:00:00 AM"`
```

As a good practice, better use `ParseExact`, where you can specify the format of input string. Try:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Well isn't this why culture info is there to begin with?

Comment: This is the format of my machine, if I change my machine to use `MM/dd/yyyy` no exception is thrown, why machine cannot be overriden?